# Float read as double

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

My code looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (void)
{ 
float x1, x2, x3;
float y1, y2, y3;
float Cos0, i, j, k, innerProduct;
float Xlength, Ylength;
x1=0;
x2=0;
x3=0;
y1=0;
y2=0;
y3=0;
Cos0=0;
i=0;
j=0;
k=0;
innerProduct=0;
Xlength=0;
Ylength=0;

printf("Please insert six floating point numbers \n");

scanf("%f%f%f%f%f%f", x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3);

Xlength=sqrt((x1*x1)+(x2*x2)+(x3*x3));

Ylength=sqrt((y1*y1)+(y2*y2)+(y3*y3));

i=x1+y1;

j=x2+y2;

k=x3+y3;

innerProduct=((x1*y1)*(x2*y2)*(x3*y3));

Cos0=(innerProduct)/((Xlength*Ylength));

return 0;
}
```

And I get the following compile errors
    "warning: format %f expects argument of type 'float *' but argument "x" has type         double"

where x is one of the digits, this happens for all 6 arguments in the scanf command, I have specified all of the variables as floats, and it doesn't like that.

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I tried it with GCC version 4.7.2 and it compiled fine

Comment: you need pass the address of the variables rather than the variables themselves.

Comment: D'oh! Well caught. :P

Comment: To get the warnings with GCC you need to add a flag (`-Wall` will do it).

Answer (score 3):

`scanf` does not work like that. You must pass *pointers* to the variables that will hold the input.

Also, in the "template" (the first parameter), the placeholders must somehow be separated - otherwise `scanf` will not know how to split up the input it gets.

This will work:

```
scanf ("%f %f %f %f %f %f", &x1, &x2, &x3, &y1, &y2, &y3);
```

For more information, read the docs. For example, http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatted-Input-Functions.html says:

> Function: int scanf (const char *template, ...)
>
> The scanf function reads formatted input from the stream stdin under the control of the template string template. The optional
>   arguments are pointers to the places which receive the resulting
>   values.

Note the "pointers" part.

---

Another question is: "Why does the warning complain about a `double`, while I passed in a `float`"? This is answered in the comp.lang.c FAQ, [question 15.10](http://c-faq.com/varargs/float.html):

> Q: I have a varargs function which accepts a float parameter. Why
>   isn't `va_arg(argp, float)` working?
>
> A: In the variable-length part of variable-length argument lists, the
>   old "default argument promotions" apply: arguments of type float are
>   always promoted (widened) to type double, and types char and short int
>   are promoted to int. Therefore, it is never correct to invoke
>   va_arg(argp, float); instead you should always use va_arg(argp,
>   double). Similarly, use va_arg(argp, int) to retrieve arguments which
>   were originally char, short, or int. (For analogous reasons, the last
>   "fixed" argument, as handed to va_start, should not be widenable,
>   either.) See also questions 11.3 and 15.2.

Note that `scanf` is a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) (or varargs function in short).

Comment: Great answer, specially for your further-reading link. Is this the reason for the strange behavior on OPs code?

Comment: Thank you so much. I completely spaced the "&" required in scanf.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the ampersands in front of the 2nd-7th arguments to `scanf()`, which I'd imagine is a very common mistake.  `scanf()`'s additional arguments are pointers to where to store the values found; it needs a reference in order to be able to save that data.

So without the ampersands, there is indeed a type mismatch.  That said, it's not obvious to me why it's mentioning `double`.